# Why won't my images align properly?

Tags: asp.net, image, background, alignment

I'm trying to make a dynamically sizable title banner, using fairly simple image tricks. I place the banner image in a table cell, and set the background-image of the table row to a one-pixel-wide repeat of the banner's right-most pixel column. Thus, the banner image appears to stretch to fit the screen width without stretching the logo. The code below is my entire page so far, and the problem is shown in a red circle in the screenshot. This is the transition where the main image ends and the one-pixel-wide background image begins.

It appears that the one-pixel-wide bar at the end is compressed by one pixel -> making the tops align properly, while the bottoms are one pixel off. I should add that I have checked the images more than once to make cure they the image data is correct. They are %100 accurate as far as MSPaint is concerned.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table style="width:100%; ">
            <tr style="background-image: url('Images/Banners/WebBannerWideBar.png')">
                                            <!--WebBannerWideBar is 1x100 px-->
                <td>
                    <img alt="Angry Octopus"
                     src="Images/Banners/WebBannerWide.png" />
                          <!--WebBannerWide is 760x100 px-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/1958/imagealignmentproblemsm.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I place the banner image in a table cell

[Don't do that](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/). This isn't 1997.

Wrap the image in a div, set the background image on the div. Adjust the padding, border and margin of the div to fit. Adjust the vertical-align of the image.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your cellspacing and cellpadding in your table to 0px.

your image might be too large for the space based on some padding you aren't aware of.

also, you could set the padding of your cell:

```
<td style="padding: 0px;"...
```